# How to show multiple roads using leaflet in R

Tags: r, shiny, traveling-salesman, r-leaflet

I am working on program connected to Traveling Salesman Problem. I use R and I load data where is lon,lng and calculate distances using osrm package. Like this:

```
distance_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(data), ncol = nrow(data))
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  for (j in i:nrow(data)) {
    if (i != j) {
      route <- osrmRoute(c(data[i,]$lng,data[i,]$lat),c(data[j,]$lng,data[j,]$lat))
      distance_matrix[i,j] <- route$distance
      distance_matrix[j,i] <- route$distance
    }
  }
}
```

My question is- Is there any way after I calculate the TSP how to show final route connecting already calculated routes(and how to save them)?

I know how to show one route like this:

```
leaflet(route) |> 
  addTiles()  |>
  addPolylines(label = ~ sprintf("%d min - %d km", round(duration), round(distance)),
               labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = FALSE))
```

but this show only one route and I would love to show after using the TSP algorithm the final smallest route(using already calculated one).

Thank u

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not using `osrm::osrmTrip()` for TSP? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60940696/646761 ,  https://github.com/riatelab/osrm/blob/master/README.md#demo

Comment: Yes, it is for my thesis and osmrTrip evaluate TSP basically on its own and I am calculating using different algorithms and also for example VRP ... thats why I need to figure out how to show it on map after calculating

Comment: @GabrielaCvečková you may find this blog post interesting https://www.jla-data.net/eng/travelling-salesman-problem-with-here/ - it uses a commercial routing engine (HERE) instead of an open source one, but I believe it comes close to what you are looking for. Feel free to drop me a line should you need some hint for your thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is just to use a distance matrix and test out different TSP approaches, I'd guess it's fine to grab that matrix from `osrm::osrmTable()`, solve your task (assuming your solvers are returning a sequence of point names or indices, i.e. row numbers of distance matrix) and get a route from `osrm::osrmRoute()` for a location sequence.
With some example data from `osrm` and `TSP` package it might look something like this:

```r
library(osrm)
#> Data: (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0 - http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
#> Routing: OSRM - http://project-osrm.org/
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

apotheke.df <- read.csv(system.file("csv/apotheke.csv", package = "osrm"))[1:10,]
apotheke.df
#>            id      lon      lat
#> 1   440338666 13.43853 52.47728
#> 2   538057637 13.57874 52.45823
#> 3   977657079 13.49039 52.61719
#> 4  3770254015 13.51974 52.49737
#> 5   364363337 13.45582 52.50112
#> 6  3666540067 13.33844 52.49479
#> 7  4234162689 13.35448 52.54872
#> 8  1492336686 13.43178 52.53216
#> 9  1298511709 13.38544 52.53797
#> 10  268726812 13.44518 52.47895

# get distnace matrices for duration and distance
distA <- osrmTable(loc = apotheke.df[c("lon", "lat")], measure = c('duration', 'distance'))

distA$durations
#>       1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
#> 1   0.0 22.6 34.7 20.7 11.4 15.0 23.6 16.0 19.7  3.9
#> 2  23.2  0.0 42.4 15.8 20.0 31.8 38.6 26.6 33.2 20.3
#> 3  34.2 40.9  0.0 30.9 27.8 34.2 24.8 20.9 24.6 35.2
#> 4  20.4 15.2 30.1  0.0 12.9 28.3 28.1 16.1 22.8 18.4
#> 5  10.2 20.2 27.3 12.2  0.0 18.1 20.0  9.3 15.5  8.2
#> 6  14.2 31.5 34.1 28.2 18.3  0.0 14.6 16.7 14.6 15.4
#> 7  20.9 38.5 24.2 26.8 18.8 14.4  0.0 13.9  6.3 21.8
#> 8  15.1 27.5 20.3 15.7  9.3 16.4 14.7  0.0  9.0 16.1
#> 9  19.1 34.2 24.3 22.5 15.2 14.3  8.3  9.2  0.0 20.0
#> 10  4.3 20.3 34.8 17.6  8.3 17.0 25.1 16.1 21.0  0.0

distA$distances
#>        1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
#> 1      0 13409 19466  9603  4813 11559 12927  8126 10522  1446
#> 2  13129     0 25491  8449 11894 24670 21309 15501 19012 11987
#> 3  19404 33675     0 18671 16446 19565 16158 12231 13538 19446
#> 4   9454  8232 18168     0  6929 15816 14800  8992 12503  9042
#> 5   4233 11909 16239  6149     0  9518 10098  5056  7841  3821
#> 6   7579 24609 19585 15946  8916     0  7604  8888  7902  7919
#> 7  11924 22042 15676 15262 10161  7477     0  7263  2989 11966
#> 8   7803 15674 12024  8893  5011  8698  8363     0  4351  7845
#> 9   9619 19259 15463 12479  7678  7696  3580  4381     0  9661
#> 10  1647 12015 20111  8626  3836  8413 12000  8683 10123     0

# a TSP tour based on durations:
tour <- 
  distA$durations |>
  as.dist() |> 
  TSP::TSP() |>
  TSP::solve_TSP()

tour
#> object of class 'TOUR' 
#> result of method 'arbitrary_insertion+two_opt' for 10 cities
#> tour length: 145

# which is basiaclly a named vector of point indeces
str(tour)
#>  'TOUR' Named int [1:10] 1 6 9 7 3 8 4 2 5 10
#>  - attr(*, "method")= chr "arbitrary_insertion+two_opt"
#>  - attr(*, "tour_length")= num 145
#>  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "1" "6" "9" "7" ...

# and can be converted to numeric or directly used for subsetting location frame
apotheke.df[tour,]
#>            id      lon      lat
#> 1   440338666 13.43853 52.47728
#> 6  3666540067 13.33844 52.49479
#> 9  1298511709 13.38544 52.53797
#> 7  4234162689 13.35448 52.54872
#> 3   977657079 13.49039 52.61719
#> 8  1492336686 13.43178 52.53216
#> 4  3770254015 13.51974 52.49737
#> 2   538057637 13.57874 52.45823
#> 5   364363337 13.45582 52.50112
#> 10  268726812 13.44518 52.47895

# and get a (single) route that passes all points in a sequence defined by `tour`
tour_sf <- osrmRoute(loc = apotheke.df[tour, c("lon", "lat")])
tour_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 13.33849 ymin: 52.45085 xmax: 13.58084 ymax: 52.62253
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>      src dst duration distance                       geometry
#> 1_10   1  10  143.905  84.1018 LINESTRING (13.43857 52.477...


leaflet(tour_sf) |> 
  addTiles()  |>
  addPolylines(label = ~ sprintf("%d min - %d km", round(duration), round(distance)),
               labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE)) |>
  addMarkers(data = apotheke.df[tour,c("lon", "lat")])
```

[image]

If you need individual segments, it would still make sense to request only routes that are part of TSP results, perhaps something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tour_segments_sf <- 
  apotheke.df[tour, ] |>
  # for destination coordinates, shift src coordinates by one row -- lead()
  mutate(across(c(lon,lat), lead, .names = "{.col}_dst")) |>
  na.omit() |>
  # osrmRoute only works with a single source, so we'll switch to rowwise grouping
  # (osrmRoute is called multiple times, once per each row)
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(route = osrmRoute(src = pick(lon, lat),
                           dst = pick(lon_dst, lat_dst))
  ) |>
  ungroup() |>
  unnest(route) |>
  st_as_sf()

tour_segments_sf |> select(id, duration, distance)
#> Simple feature collection with 9 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 13.33849 ymin: 52.45085 xmax: 13.57897 ymax: 52.62253
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>           id duration distance                                          geometry
#>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>                                  <LINESTRING [°]>
#> 1  440338666    15.0     11.6  (13.43857 52.47726, 13.44109 52.47274, 13.44235 …
#> 2 3666540067    14.6      7.90 (13.33849 52.4947, 13.34093 52.49981, 13.34624 5…
#> 3 1298511709     8.30     3.58 (13.38536 52.53791, 13.38357 52.5388, 13.38234 5…
#> 4 4234162689    24.2     15.7  (13.35467 52.54884, 13.35226 52.5504, 13.36443 5…
#> 5  977657079    20.9     12.2  (13.49051 52.61729, 13.49096 52.6167, 13.48765 5…
#> 6 1492336686    15.7      8.89 (13.43168 52.5322, 13.43243 52.53284, 13.4345 52…
#> 7 3770254015    15.2      8.23 (13.5196 52.4976, 13.52036 52.49818, 13.51961 52…
#> 8  538057637    20.0     11.9  (13.57897 52.45816, 13.57624 52.45456, 13.57197 …
#> 9  364363337     8.24     3.82 (13.45592 52.5011, 13.45536 52.5003, 13.46432 52…

leaflet(tour_segments_sf) |> 
  addTiles()  |>
  addPolylines(label = ~ sprintf("%d min - %d km", round(duration), round(distance)),
               labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE)) |>
  addMarkers(data = apotheke.df[tour,c("lon", "lat")])
```

[image]

If it would not work for you, please add more details regarding your constraints and scope of your work.

Depends on the actual problem and topic, but for thesis, I would have assumed that http://project-osrm.org/ or any other remotely hosted routing service is not an option and you'd need to host your own osrm for experiments and/or work with OpenStreetMap data and network analysis tools (i.e. `igraph`, `sfnetworks`).

Comment: Thank you this helped, I have just one additional question regarding the tour, does it also return to the origin town? because TSP is formulated that the starting point and the ending point are the same but when I show it like this it does not show the final route to the starting point.

Comment: It depends on your implementation.  TSP package (that was used here just as a placeholder) returns a sequence of 10 locations  (`str(tour)` output) and 10-1 segments for 10x10 distance matrix, at least by default. If you need a closed loop, just make sure your TSP implementation appends the first location index to the end as well.

Comment: @margsul: great answer! Do you have any ideas about this question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78156582/taking-screenshots-from-stackoverflow-using-r